# docker AWS SAM local not connecting to docker dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, sam

so after generating the AWS SAM template 'web-backend' lambda my functions do not connect to my dynamodb docker instance.

This is the JavaScript code I'm using:

```
const docClient = new dynamoDb.DocumentClient({region: 'localhost', endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'});
const data = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
```

and running in my terminal:

```
sam local start-api --docker-network lambda-local
```

&

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --network=lambda-local amazon/dynamodb-local
```

hitting the generated endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` the terminal gives the error :

```
ERROR   Invoke Error    {"errorType":"NetworkingError","errorMessage":"connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000","code":"NetworkingError","message":"connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":8000,"region":"localhost","hostname":"localhost","retryable":true,"time":"2021-01-03T15:21:11.468Z","stack":["Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000","    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)"]}
```

and if i try and hit the dynamodb through postman I get:

```
{
    "__type": "com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#MissingAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Request must contain either a valid (registered) AWS access key ID or X.509 certificate."
}
```

So the dynamodb server is running as i can connect to it via the noSQL workbench but my assumption is the docker container for the sam local api can't see the docker container for the dynamodb?

Any ideas will be much appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I can almost guarantee you this is a Docker networking issue. When you have two containers like this that need to talk to each other, it almost always is. I recommend you use Docker Compose which sets up all of this for you and it is far easier. The [DynamoDB documentation gives you a template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html).

For the access ID error thing, you need to run `aws configure` where you are running Postman. The ID and such can be anything, but it has to have something populated.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment! The AWS and SAM sdk's set up the docker images for you so I don't think it's possible to run them in the same container (please correct me if i'm wrong though) so thats why i was trying to use a docker network to connect the two

Comment: I was not saying to run them in the same container. I was saying to just launch the two containers using Compose. That way, the networking is taken care for you.

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I work for AWS as a Serverless Developer Advocate and work directly with SAM often. This is not an answer to your question, but I would heavily encourage you away from this pattern. SAM local can hit DynamoDB in the cloud as easily as it hits DDB local. In fact, it is easier because you do not have to wrestle with the Docker network. I talk through it in this video. Hope it helps! https://youtu.be/NzPqMrdgD1s

Comment: Thank you, would that not be quite costly to use a hosted DDB in a local env?

Comment: Adding to the comment above, especially when running tests locally and in CI?

Comment: The cost (based on us-east-1/on-demand pricing) is $1.25 per million writes and $0.25 per million reads. 25 GB of storage is free and $0.25 per GB after that. Most likely your cost will be roughly $1.50 a month unless you are going over a million read and writes for testing. I feel like $1.50 is worth my peace of mind in knowing it just works. https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/

Comment: Yeah I agree, thanks so much for your advice!

Comment: I'd disagree. Having a local DynamoDB simulator (any a simulator for any other AWS service) significantly eases building automated, self-contained tests that can be run easily on any machine, be it a CI/CD server or the developer's own machine.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the way you're trying to hit the local dynamodDb endpoint at `endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'`

In the sam local container `127.0.0.1` refers to that container, not the dynamodb local container.

To solve this, you can give the dynamodb local container a name when you start it and then change your endpoint to `http://name_of_the_dynamodb_container:8000` and it will work.

For example, start your dynamodb local like so:

```
docker run -name ddb_local -d -p 8000:8000 --network=lambda-local amazon/dynamodb-local
```

Then configure the connection in your other container like so:

```
const docClient = new dynamoDb.DocumentClient({region: 'localhost', endpoint: 'http://ddb_local:8000/'});
const data = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
```

This is not the only way, but it should work for you.

I think Eric Johnson is right that when doing local development you almost never want to use dynamodb local for anything other than running hermetic unit tests but still, it's nice to be able to do it.

Comment: Okay thanks, I did try this approach but i'll double check it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was caused by the machine OS. This is what I found, you need to use the following endpoints:

Mac OSX: `endpoint_url="http://docker.for.mac.localhost:8000/"`

Windows: `endpoint_url="http://docker.for.windows.localhost:8000/"`

Linux: `endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000/"`

With that my project works!